# I can't select unique text from template_id

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select template_id, text
from questionary_eventlog qe
where template_id in (26, 217)
group by template_id
limit 2
```

What I have

| template_id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 26 | you have a bonuce/azmm/eee |
| 26 | you have a bonuce/azmm/fff |

What I need

| template_id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 26 | you have a bonuce/azmm/eee |
| 217 | you are winner /azmm/fff |

What i tried

```
select template_id, text
from questionary_eventlog qe
where template_id in (26, 217)
and
text = (select distinct left(text,17) from questionary_eventlog
group by template_id
limit 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want a correct group by aggregation

```
select template_id, max(text) text
from questionary_eventlog qe
where template_id in (26, 217)
group by template_id
```